# Changing codec of webcam is not possible using OpenCV/Python

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, video-capture, codec

I am using windows 10 and python 3.7 / OpenCV4 and a Logitech C922 webcam. While the cam seems to provide 30 fps using the windows camera app, i can not get more than 5-6 fps using OpenCV. Resolution is set to FHD.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW+0)
while(1):
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

In another post I found the solution to change the codec to MJPG. However, the camera does not accept changing the codec. I tried:

```
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','j','p','g'))
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'))
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'))
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, float(cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','j','p','g'))
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, float(cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'))
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, 1196444237.0)
```

The camera always returns "844715353.0"

How can I achieve higher fps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that order matters. As I understand, OpenCv uses ffmpeg in the background. In ffmpeg the command should be something like this:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i video="my webcam" out.mkv
```

So that your OpenCV code should be something like this

```
my_cam_index = 0 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(my_cam_index, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60.0) 
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720) 
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('M','J','P','G'))
```

Answer (score 0):

i work with Logitech c920 webcam and i test `WebcamVideoStream` class in `imutils` module and this module use threading and the queue data structure for improve the FPS when processing video streams with OpenCV is to move the I/O (i.e., the reading of frames from the camera sensor) to a separate thread, and you can set your custom resolution on this file `webcamvideostream.py`.

you can use threading to obtain higher FPS. maybe this solution help you.

plz see these links:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/

https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/video/webcamvideostream.py

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, I think multithreading will only increase pseudo fps. That means, I read a lot more frames, but many frames are just the former and not new frames as the physical framerate of the camera won't change. Only the program body is executed a lot more. If you use FHD resolution, what "physical" fps can you achieve? And which codec do you use? Thanks a lot

Comment: your welcome, i use c920 camera long time ago and i dont remember what it was, but i use 1920x1080 resolution, and when i use multithreadin i can improve my fps, and i wanted to real time image processing from uav robot.